# Table contains 4 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 3 defined in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.5, mariadb-5.5

The database is an old version of MariaDB, the equivalent of MySQL 5.5. The table contains those columns

```
id
auth
old_auth
device_id_fk
```

This error is showing

`Table contains 4 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 3 defined in MySQL`

The results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

```
CREATE TABLE `wtb_device_auths` (

  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `device_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,

  `auth` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

  `old_auth` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  KEY `auth_index` (`auth`),

  KEY `auth1_index` (`device_id_fk`),

  KEY `auth2_index` (`old_auth`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=627642 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Delete your foto. Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` on both servers, copy returned table scripts and paste them into your question. And - where is your question?

Comment: @Akina Okay, as for where is my question, I want to fix the error `Table contains 4 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 3 defined in MySQL`

Comment: @Akina There's only 1 server

Comment: *This error is showing* I do NOT see any error... where is it? *the number of indexes 3 defined in MySQL* Where this data is taken from?

Comment: @Akina From mariadb error log apparently, I don't have access to the server, it's managed by the client offline (no internet access)

Comment: Post the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: @JesusUzcanga I just posted them

Comment: Try `ANALYZE TABLE wtb_device_auths;`, if  that doesn't work, then try with `OPTIMIZE TABLE wtb_device_auths;`

Comment: I had a look in the MariaDB code for 5.5 compared to 10.5 around where this error is generated. There is one change related to [MDEV-9918](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9918) which is largely just changing the way errors are reported. It seems the cause there was a crash during an altering of the table and the frm and innodb table definitions are different. I recommend an `ALTER TABLE wtb_device_auths FORCE` to recreate it would like to see that confirmed from others here before doing it.

Answer (score 3):

The error is related to the difference between Innodb definition and the frm file definition.

It probably occurred because of a crash during an `ALTER TABLE` or similar statement at some point.

To restore the consistency an `ALTER TABLE wtb_device_auths FORCE` will recreate the table (while exclusively locking it). This recreation should make both the innodb and frm definitions consistent.

Comment: Recreation.. does it preserve data?

Comment: Yes. Though take a backup with mysqldump or logically similar for this table just to be sure.